# Get likes count of URL with multiple $get variables using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve likes count of several urls from multiple sources.

Most of these URLs are in the form `http://www.example.com/article.php?a=1&b=2&c=3` and when I try to use the Graph API to get likes count, Facebook stops at the first $get variable (a=1, in the example).

This is not the same URL so I don't get what I am looking for. Is there any other method to get data about the URL I want ? Is using the PHP SDK will solve the problem ?

Comment: Did you try to `urlencode` the URL before requesting the API ?

Comment: afters some time looking for the right answer, I just found that the best way to do so is through FQL. Here's how I'm doing it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773137/how-to-get-facebook-shares-and-likes-of-url/17773138#17773138